# How can we find the coefficients of a polynomial given the coordinates of 3 points?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I tried solving the system of $3$ equation for this, and it's actually very hard. I'm just trying to find the coefficients $A,B,C$, of the polynomial $Ax^2+Bx+C$ given the points  $(a,b)  (c,d)  (e,f)$.

Comment: Using both $a$ and $A$ is a bit dangerous

Comment: It's the same kind of elimination as with 2 equations. Subtract some multiple of one equation from the other two to eliminate the first term (a different multiple for each). Then you're left with two equations in two unknowns. Which presumably you're comfortable solving.

Comment: I mean, is there a formula to calculate $A, B, C$ ? For example, with 2 points, you get a 1 degree polynomial ($Ax+B$). And in this example, $A=\frac{a-c}{b-d}$ if I remember correctly. Is there such formulas in this case for all coefficients?

Comment: Why don't you write the system of equations?

Comment: I don't have the time rn

Comment: We don’t have time then either. Anyhow, you might want to look at Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: There's no reason being so rude seriously

Comment: There's no reason to be so helpless. These other users are trying to help you, Pierre, but they're expecting you to put in a little effort yourself.

Comment: I was at a conference, I didn't have time to look "how to do that in latex" and put everything down.

Comment: A user found the time to write out a solution to your problem, Pierre. Are you going to find the time to "accept" that user's answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it?

Comment: I guess not. From someone who was quick to complain about the perceived rudeness of others, this is inexcusable.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the three points are $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) , (x_3, y_3) $

Then it follows that

$ A x_1^2 + B x_1 + C = y_1 $

$ A x_2^2 + B x_2 + C = y_2 $

$ A x_3^2 + B x_3 + C = y_3 $

Using Cramer's rule, the three parameters $A,B,C$ are given by

$ A = \dfrac{1}{D} \begin{vmatrix} y_1 && x_1 && 1 \\ y_2 && x_2 && 1 \\ y_3 && x_3 && 1 \end{vmatrix} $

$ B =  \dfrac{1}{D} \begin{vmatrix} x_1^2 && y_1 && 1 \\ x_2^2 && y_2 && 1 \\ x_3^2 && y_3 && 1 \end{vmatrix} $

$ C =  \dfrac{1}{D} \begin{vmatrix} x_1^2 && x_1 && y_1 \\ x_2^2 && x_2 && y_2 \\ x_3^2 && x_3 && y_3 \end{vmatrix} $

where

$D = \begin{vmatrix} x_1^2 && x_1 && 1 \\ x_2^2 && x_2 && 1 \\ x_3^2 && x_3 && 1 \end{vmatrix} $

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this post has answered your question to your satisfaction, Pierre, the way to indicate that is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to it. If you're not satisfied with the answer, you could leave a comment indicating what is unsatisfactory about it.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, Pierre.